# Benchmark Model for Path-Dependant Monte Carlo Simulations?

Tags: monte-carlo, asset-pricing, sde, best-practices

As part of my research for my masters thesis, I'm testing out the effectiveness of some different models in Monte Carlo simulations for path dependant options.

I will be attempting a model-free approach to simulating price paths so these will simply be used as a benchmark. I want to choose a few models which are valid and commonly used for MC simulations today.

So far I have implemented Black-Scholes (the classic), Merton's Jump Diffusion model and a Heston stochastic volatility model. Are these commonly used in practice today? Are there any other models which should be included?

Comment: Among the commonly used models, Local-Stochastic models are very  commonly used. They combine the nice stochastic behaviour of pure stochastic volatility models, like Heston, which the ability to match option prices in the local volatility model.
Those are a bit tougher to calibrate and and the theory is more involved though, so it might be overkill in your thesis.

Comment: Thank you @JesperTidblom

I will take a look. If it ends up taking too much of my time budget I'll call it overkill :) Is there any resource you would recommend as a starting point?